# Synchronizing data on QField

Tags: qfield

I was currently collecting some data using QField. I synchronized the data and it successfully downloaded the freshly updated project from the QField Cloud... but am not able to see the data already picked on my Android.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have synchronized the data on Qfield but am not able to see the point features I was digiziting